# OnSharedPreferencesChanged is not called after changing preferences any other method than using EditTextPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I have `PreferenceFragment`. Inside this fragment I have an `OnSharedPreferencesChanged` like this:

```
@Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences preference, String key) {
            Preference pref = findPreference(key);
            pref.setSummary(preference.getString(key, ""));
        }
```

And I bind `listener` like this:

```
@Override
        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
                    .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
                    .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        }
```

When I change some data just typing it in `EditTextPrefence` it changes as expected. But I'd like to have different method of changing my preferences beside just typing it. I'm struggling with geographical coordinates so I want to change latitude and longitude of given item using `PlacePicker`.

Here is piece of my code that retrieves location picked from `PlacePicker`:

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            Place place = getPlace(getActivity(), data);
            LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
            double latitude = latLng.latitude;
            double longitude = latLng.longitude;

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

            Preference longitudePreference = findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_car_longitude_key));
            longitudePreference.setSummary(String.valueOf(longitude));
            Preference latitudePreference = findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_car_latitude_key));
            latitudePreference.setSummary(String.valueOf(latitude));

            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.pref_car_longitude_key), String.valueOf(longitude)).apply();
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.pref_car_latitude_key), String.valueOf(latitude)).apply();

}
```

My problem is that I have to keep lines like these  `latitudePreference.setSummary(String.valueOf(latitude));` to make my preferences screen being updated after location is picked from the map and lines like these `sharedPreferences.edit().putString(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_car_longitude_key), String.valueOf(longitude)).apply();` to keep my `SharedPrefences` being updated. When I remove `setSummary` then summary on preferences screen is not updated and I believe it should since I'm changing my SharedPreferences. Shouldn't then `OnSharedPreferencesChanged` method be called and update the summary?

Comment: Are you calling `onSharedPreferenceChanged` for each of your keys in your onCreatePreferences() method?

Answer (score 1):

First off, changing the summaries will not ever call an onPreferenceChanged listener because the preference didn't change.  Just the graphical representation.  The actual preference is just the key->value pair.

Secondly, you need to call at least commit, if not apply, to get the listener called.  Until then you're planning to change the setting, but you haven't actually changed it until apply/commit is called.

Comment: I use .apply() but .commit() didn't work as well. I change these key-value pairs as you said but `OnSharedPreferencesChanged` is not called to change its graphical representation and I'm trying to figure out why.